# Why doesn't @Transactional roll back after NullPointerException is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a method which can throw a NullPointerException. The method is marked with `@Transactional`.

My code structure is as follows:

```
public void outer() {
    try {
        inner();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // exception caught
    }     
}

@Transactional
public void inner() {
    database.saveStuff();
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

After running the above code, the database updates inside `inner()` are not rolled back. What could cause such problem?

As per my understanding, the database actions should be rolled back if the exception is "visible" to the annotation. In this case meaning that the `inner()` method is marked with `@Transactional` and throws the exception instead of catching it.

It *might* also be worth mentioning that the method `outer()` is also called inside another `@Transactional` method, which in turn is inside a `try catch`. However, the exception is not visible to that method because it's caught inside `outer()`, so as per my understanding it shouldn't matter.

I tried to search for answers on the web, but all the answers seem to be about checked Exceptions (e.g. `java.lang.Exception`) not automatically being rolled back. Because `NullPointerException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, that shouldn't be an issue here.

Somebody in my team also suggested to use this cluster of annotations, but it didn't make any difference:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling `inner()` directly. Spring AOP only works with bean method since `inner()` is called directly it won't be proxied and the interceptors are not added.

As you mentioned the `outer` method is called from a method with `@Transactional` So, you should either remove the `try-catch` or rethrow the exception.